# Reportlab doesn't process & and <

Tags: django, reportlab

I'm using Django and Reportlab to generate pdf files.  Occasionally a user will use a character that Reportlab determines to be invalid, and I get this:

*ValueError: xml parser error (bogus < or &) in paragraph...*

Is there any way to avoid this other than restricting the input from the user?

Here is a stripped down version of the code:

```
def generate_report(request, obj_id):

    obj = Model.objects.get(pk=obj_id)
    width, height = letter
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + "/pdf/" + str(obj.id) + ".pdf", pagesize=letter,rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,topMargin=160,bottomMargin=100)
    Story = []        

    Story.append('Title', h1))

    text = obj.test_to_display
    for line in text.splitlines():
        Story.append(Spacer(1,0.1*inch))
        p = Paragraph(line, style)
        Story.append(p)        

    doc.build(Story)

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/media/pdf/" + str(obj.id) + ".pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never directly used ReportLab before, but based on the error message it should be as simple is converting those characters to html entities.

Here is a quick guide on how to use the python cgi library to do this quickly and easily:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Or maybe the xml specific version would be slightly better since it appears reportlab is generating xml along the way and that's where it's breaking (though the majority of character entities are shared)
http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the issue of the & character before, when creating titles.

I solved it by doing the following:

```
from cgi import escape
Paragraph(escape(self.name), self.styles['cover_subtitle'])
```

Perhaps you could try:

```
from cgi import escape
p = Paragraph(escape(line), style)
```

Hope this helps!